# Java Web service to Sharepoint Query

Tags: java, sharepoint, caml

I am querying a list on sharepoint via java via a webservice.
It works fine when I want to get the whole list, but I want to 
query only part of the list. It can be done via a CAML query like this:

```
<Query>
<Where>
   <Gt>
      <FieldRef Name='ID' />
      <Value Type='Number'>10</Value>
   </Gt>
</Where>
</Query>
```

I'm not sure how to pass this via Java though..
Now I'm doing this:

```
GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = port.getListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, webID);
```

Where QUERY object is simply null (which fetches the whole list).

I read somewhere it can be done like this:

```
GetListItems.Query query = new GetListItems.Query();
query.getContent().add(generateXmlNode(QueryStringHere));
```

But I don't have the generateXmlNode method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I answer this for people that might have the same issue and get here, even if its 2 years old.

```
private static Object generateXmlNode(String string) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document rootDocument = docBuilder.newDocument();
    rootDocument.setTextContent(string);
    return rootDocument.getDocumentElement();

}
```

The param `String string` is in this case the query as XML (CAML). 
It can be loaded e.g. from a property:

```
this.query = new String(readAll(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/Query.xml").toURI())));
this.queryOptions = new String(readAll(new File( this.getClass().getResource( "/QueryOptions.xml").toURI())));
```

and the query could look like this:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Contains> 
                <FieldRef Name="Editor" /> 
                <Value Type="Text">Chandler</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Contains> 
                <FieldRef Name="FileRef" /> 
                <Value Type="Text">AuditDeleteTesting</Value>
            </Contains>     
        </And>
        <Eq> 
            <FieldRef Name="Created_x0020_Date" /> 
            <Value Type="DateTime">2013-09-11</Value>
        </Eq>               
    </And>      

    </Where>
</Query>
```

And the queryOption:

```
<QueryOptions>
    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
    <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/> 
    <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc> 
</QueryOptions>
```

I would recommend to use the SharePoint Query Helper if you are not common with CAML Queries:
https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

I hope it helps.

edit: I forgot to mention the source: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html?null

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [query] root node. query node will be added by sharepoint at runtime. That should fix your problem.

Comment: THis could be,  but it's another problem then. I'm asking for something else. the query is passed as an object to the port.getLIstItems() method. THough I'm not sure which object it is. I'd like to simply pass the xml string, but that's not possible. Any idea what object I have to make to pass the query to getlistitems()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private static Object generateXmlNode(String string) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document rootDocument = docBuilder.newDocument();
    rootDocument.setTextContent(string);
    return rootDocument.getDocumentElement();

}
```